# Flutter integration for Google Assistant & Siri - voice interactions

Tags: flutter, google-assistant-sdk, siri, sirikit, google-voice-actions

I want to build an app with Google Assistant & Siri support.
How would one go about implementing this in Flutter?
I'm aware of [existing voice support](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter#voice),
but there's no support for back-and-forth voice actions...

Thanks!

Comment: check this answer. I believe you would need to use platform channels to use the native code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551863/using-onesignal-with-flutter/50553712#50553712

Comment: @Tree Cool, I see platform channels support calling Dart from native as well as native from Dart. Great, thanks for the references!
(Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I'll approve it.)

Comment: Were u able to make this work? We are looking at doing this as well

Comment: @SamCromer I ended up not using Flutter, but the above answer should do the trick. Note that Google Assistant's voice interactions only work for apps already on Play Store. You might want to take a look at other APIs. Good luck!